# Haskell no instance for (Eq Digit) arising from a use of == In the expression: x == One

Tags: haskell, binary

```
data Digit = Zero | One
convBNum :: [Digit] -> Int
convBNum [] = 0
convBNum (x:xs)
  | x == One = 2^length xs + convBNum xs
  | otherwise = convBNum xs
```

This is the code of a simple function that converts a binary number into an int; when I compile it, it gives me this error:

```
no instance for (Eq Digit) arising from a use of == 
In the expression: x == One
```

If I understood well, also reading other questions, the problem is that x can't be anytype, but I couldn't understand how to fix this and how to use Eq constraint.

Comment: Others have mentioned that you can and should derive `Eq` and `Show`. I thought I should mention that you likely should also derive `Ord`, `Enum`, and perhaps `Read`. In GHC, it's also often helpful to derive `Generic`, but that requires an extra import and a language extension, and you don't really need that yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the problem is that x can't be anytype

In your code `x` has type `Digit` and that's exactly the type it should have. That's not the problem.

The problem is that the `==` operator is defined in the `Eq` type class. This means that it can only be used on types that are instances of that type class, which your `Digit` type is not. To make it one, you could supply your own definition of `==` for `Digit` like this:

```
instance Eq Digit where
    Zero == Zero = True
    One == One = True
    _ == _ = False
```

However definitions for some type classes (like `Eq`, `Ord`, `Show` and `Read`) can be automatically defined for custom data types by using the `deriving` keyword, which is usually preferable. So you could write:

```
data Digit = Zero | One deriving Eq
```

And this will generate the above `Eq` instance automatically.

Note that for your use case, using nested pattern matching would be more idiomatic than using `==`:

```
convBNum :: [Digit] -> Int
convBNum [] = 0
convBNum (One : xs) = 2^length xs + convBNum xs
convBNum (Zero : xs) = convBNum xs
```

This way you don't even need the `Eq` instance, but it makes sense to have it anyway as `Digit` is a type that really should support `==`.

On an unrelated note, you should probably also either derive or manually define an instance for `Show`, so that you can `print` digits and display them in GHCi.

Answer (score 8):

Add a `deriving` clause

```
data Digit = Zero | One deriving (Eq)
```

or do not use `==`, and use pattern matching instead:

```
convBNum (One:xs) = 2^length xs + convBNum xs
convBNum (_  :xs) =               convBNum xs
```